# Querying value from a specific xml tag with a specific attribute using Linq C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this xml file where I am trying to get some tags from.
Here is the thing... I want to extract the tags that has a specific attribute with a specific value...

Here is an example

```
<root>
    <input class="x">Data</input>
    <input>Data2</input>
    <input name="y">Data3</input>
    <input class="z">Data4</input>
</root>
```

I want to get all the "input" tags that has the attribute "class".

```
List<XElement> selected = xmlDoc.Descendants("input").Where(t => t.Element("input").Attributes("class") != null).ToList();
```

but it gives me a null reference exception in the lambda expression... Would you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t.Attributes("class")` will never return null. Use `t.Attribute("class")` instead (or `.Where(t => t.Attributes("class").Any())`).

You don't also need `t.Element("input")`

```
var selected = xmlDoc.Descendants("input")
                      .Where(t => t.Attribute("class") != null)
                      .ToList();
```

or simply

```
var selected = xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("//input[@class]").ToList();
```

with the help of XPATH

Answer (score 0):

You'll want this

```
List<XElement> selected = xmlDoc.Descendants("input").Where(t => t.Attribute("class") != null).ToList();
```

You were trying to look at input nodes inside of input nodes.